# Push array into JSON Object, Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am trying my best to program an angular app. I have a problem pushing an empty array into an object.

I get an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

I have an object called items which looks like this:

```
Object

 {
  "Name": "name",
  "Description": "description"
 }
```

I would like to push an empty array into the object that can contain another array. Something like this.

```
Object

 {
  "Name": "name",
  "Description": "description",
  "Related Items": {
                    Item1:{...},
                    Item2:{...},
                    ...
                   }
 }
```

My controller does this when it is called:

```
$scope.push = function () {
  $scope.item.push({"Related Items":[]});
};
```

I know I must be getting mixed up with something simple about the JSON Objects and Arrays, but I can't seem to find a solution.

Thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `item` is an object, you can just set the `Related Items` property:

```
$scope.item["Related Items"] = [];
$scope.item["Related Items"].push({});
```

However, above it looks like `Related Items` is actually an object with key names `Item1`, etc. rather than an array.

```
$scope.item["Related Items"] = {};
$scope.item["Related Items"].Item1 = {};
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript's `push` function only works when you're pushing values to an array.  It won't work if you try to push to an object, instead it will try to call the key of "push" which doesn't exist.  That's why you're getting the error you're getting.

Make sure that `$scope.item` is an array (`[]` or `new Array`), and then push to it with the value you would like.

```
$scope.item = [];
$scope.push = function () {
  $scope.item.push({"Related Items":[]});
};
```

[Here's](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) W3School's .push() method explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The item object should be like 
{
....
"Related Items":<"some value">
....
}

It should already have key.